# object array normals changing along curve

Tags: modifiers

In order to model a zipper, I duplicated an edge from the cloth and converted it to a bezier curve. Then I attached an array and a curve modifier to a helper plane. Eventually I parented the zipper tooth to the plane. This workflow is recommended for Blender 2.8 in order to avoid object distortion.
It works with one exception: the plane normals and thus the tooth orientation change along the bezier curve. It starts out fine:

[image]

but further up along the curve the plane normals incline:

[image]

I would expect the plane normals to stay parallel to the bezier curve along the whole distance.

Well, the bezier curve itself changes direction as well, but the plane normals should follow that change and not rotate relative to the curve.

I've been fiddling with this for some time now and can't find an explanation / a solution. Please help.

[Link to .blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11J9F1C0uNcK8Swe8gQTK_bjEt26xUAP1)

Comment: I _think_ all you need to do is Ctrl A > apply the scale of your curve. Always watch out for non-uniform scaling in object-level transforms.

Comment: That did it. Question answered. Thank you.